# Laravel Authentication Issue for Version 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have issue of authentication. In version 5.1 it's working fine in local but on server getting weird error. `check()` function always return false but I had debug in authentication controller I got the true in `attempt()` function but why `check()` return false after redirection?

config/auth.php:

```
return [

    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'App\Company',
    'table' => 'company',
    'password' => [
        'email' => 'emails.password',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
];
```

Company model class

```
<?php

namespace Testnamespace;

use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableInterface;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\SluggableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Sofa\Eloquence\Eloquence;

class Company extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract, SluggableInterface
{

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, SoftDeletes, SluggableTrait, Eloquence;

    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'company';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'name',
        'info',
        'extra_info',
        'phone',
        'mobile',
        'street',
        'postal_code',
        'website',
        'facebook',
        'newsletter'
    ];
    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to' => 'slug',
    ];
    protected $searchableColumns = ['name'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';


}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: No error message but auth::check() function return false

Comment: any other configuration required except config/auth.php and config/session.php ??

Comment: Have you checked error log? or checked the session with correct domain?

Comment: I have checked error log there is no error in that and try to set domain in config/session.php but issue remain same.

Comment: Can we see your `Company` model class?

Comment: I have edit my question and add model class please have a look

Comment: Please check this [laravel.io/forum](http://laravel.io/forum/11-11-2014-authcheck-always-returning-false) if it solves this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using subdomain then change this line below (config/session)

```
'domain' => null,
```

to

```
'domain' => '.yourdomain.com',
```

Also if you are using files to store session

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

then check if you have write permission given to storage/framework/sessions directory . you also can try changing database sessions .

Comment: i have try to set domain but no luck same issue

Comment: i Have been facing similar issue with related to domain . i found that there may be issue related to server path and symbolic link where actual path is different and code location is different on server .

Comment: any other suggestion??